# How to use DSR load balnce from two different network?

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, haproxy, ip-routing

I have a server (A) which clients connect to it throw internet and its ip is 195.45.10.2 it route trafic to server (B) and its ip is 85.10 20.2 . So now I want to use some thing like dsr to let server b directly send packets to clients.
Client send to A and A send to B then B respons to client directly.
So it is needed to request packets from A to B have client ip address as source and then response packets from B to client have server A ip address as source ip address.

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine with using DSR mode for that scenario, as long as:

Server A has direct network access to Server B i.e. at least one interface on the same subnet.

And Server B has direct access to respond to the client over the Internet via any valid route.

However I just checked and NGINX only seems to support UDP mode for DSR and not TCP?
https://www.nginx.com/blog/ip-transparency-direct-server-return-nginx-plus-transparent-proxy/

LVS supports it just fine and we've been using it for years:
http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/
https://www.loadbalancer.org/blog/layer-4-vs-layer-7-load-balancing-we-still-love-dsr/

Comment: As I searched I can use l3dsr for this problem. Because my 2 servers are in different subnets. But I did not find any step by step tutorial to setup l3dsr . So if somebody know about it I will approtiate him